# Prevent CSS animation overlap on transform:scale increase

Tags: css

I have an image that will animate to grow in scale. While the growth increases underneath the `header` element, it persists in growing over the top of the `div2` element. I tried `z-index` and other such things without luck :(

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  
  document.getElementById("div1").style.height = window.innerHeight 
   - document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight
   - document.getElementById("div2").offsetHeight
   + "px";
});
```

```css
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header {
  background-color:yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}


#div2 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#imgGrow {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: imgGrow 2s ease forwards;
  object-fit: cover;
}
        
@keyframes imgGrow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
Header
</header>  

<main>
     <div id="div1">
        <img id="imgGrow" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg/1200px-Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg">
      </div>
      <div id="div2">
      1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6
      </div>
</main>
```

Comment: It isn’t really possible to see the problem in the current snippet as the calculated height is negative. Perhaps include a recalculation on resize so it’s discernable on going to full page?

Comment: Add `position: relative` for `#div2`, that is already sufficient.

Comment: @CBroe post as answer and I'll mark as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` for `#div2`, is already sufficient.

(Your attempts at using `z-index` likely did not work, because you did not position the element you tried to apply it to. `z-index` only works on positioned elements.)